# How can I display this output with 3 joins in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

SQL> select * from Art_Object;

```
    ID YEAR                      TITLE                     DES                       A_NAME
```

---

```
     1 1890                      Old Man                   An old man in the dark    van Gogh
     2 1894                      Cat                       White cat in black canvas van Gogh
     3 1853                      Monalisa                  Smiling woman             Leonardo
     4 1888                      The meeting               Two men talking           Picaso
     5 2017                      The crimson stone         Group of characters       Omar
```

SQL> select * from painting;

```
    ID PAINT_TYPE                     MATERIAL                       STYLE
```

---

```
     2 Oil Painting                   Oil                            Cubism
     3 Satin                          Paint                          Expressionism
```

SQL> select * from sculpture;

```
    ID MATERIAL                           HEIGHT     WEIGHT STYLE
```

---

```
     4 Mud                                   172        180 Cubism
```

SQL> select * from other;

```
    ID TYPE                           STYLE
```

---

```
     1 3D painting                    Realist
     5 Digital Painting               Manga
```

SQL>

*The query says (What is the type of the oldest art object in the museum?) so i was thinking i need to join these 4 tables and display the minimum year which is "int" here with the (paint_type from Painting or Material from Sculpture or Type from Other), displaying in the out put the (type) and the (year)*

Comment: @Sami Him and I are working on the same project

Comment: The oldest object is from 1853 with `id` = 3, but there is no `id` = 3 in the table `other` that you have displayed in the last. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a traditional way to solve this:

```
select ao.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from painting p where p.id = ao.id) then 'painting'
             when exists (select 1 from sculpture s where s.id = ao.id) then 'sculpture'
             when exists (select 1 from other o where o.id = ao.id) then 'other'
        end) as art_type             
from art_object ao
order by year, id
fetch first one row only;
```

Not all databases support `fetch first`; however, all have some way of accomplishing this.

Also, this returns just one oldest, if multiple objects are tied.

EDIT:

In Oracle pre-12, you can do:

```
select ao.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from painting p where p.id = ao.id) then 'painting'
             when exists (select 1 from sculpture s where s.id = ao.id) then 'sculpture'
             when exists (select 1 from other o where o.id = ao.id) then 'other'
        end) as art_type             
from (select ao.*, rownum as seqnum
      from art_object ao
      order by ao.year desc
     ) ao
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks it is working except for the fetch , i'm using Oracle g11

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm sorry to be bother but would you mind explaining it to me so I can understand

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, like this:

```
SELECT
  o1.A_Name,
  o1.Year,
  p.Paint_type,
  s.MATERIAL, s.HEIGHT, s.WEIGHTSTYLE,
  o.TYPE,o.STYLE
FROM Art_Object as o1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT ID, MIN(Year) AS Oldest
   FROM Art_Object 
   GROUP BY ID
) AS o2 ON o1.ID = o2.ID AND o1.Year = o2.Oldest
INNER JOIN painting as p ON o1.ID = p.ID
INNER JOIN sculpture AS s ON o1.ID = s.ID
INNER JOIN other as o ON o1.ID = o.ID
```